# Delay Loading A SelectInput List

Tags: r, shiny

I am in the midst of creating a Shiny App - I have it working well, but would like to add some flexibility for the user. I run a package that downloads live data from a website. I run several calculations and output a ggplot vis. It is a horizontal segment-bar graph - broken up time intervals are calculated and plotted.

I would now like to add a drop down list that users can filter up to 6 inputs (y values) for the graph. At any point there is up to 30-34 unique y value inputs.

The issue I am running up against is that the filter list for the drop-down is only available after a calculation completed by an observer event. I want there to be no drop-down list on page load, and once my plot loads, it can show up and I can reference the proper data frame. Here is the code I am working off of - I'd like to have a checkbox to dynamically display all the six input options once clicked.

```
checkboxInput("FILTER", "CHOOSE INPUTS"),    
conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.FILTER == true",
             selectInput("input.1", "CHOOSE FIRST INPUT",
                         c("All", 
                           unique(as.character(df$Name)))
```

As can be seen, df$Name will not be calculated on page load and therefore the application cannot run. Is there a way to only show the SelectInput drop-down lists once I run all my regular code? I figure it may be possible to tie to a submit button that runs my initial code?

This is my UI.R prior to adding the SelectInput's:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           h3("LIVE CHART",align = "center"))),
  br(), #BREAK BETWEEN HEADER AND CONTENT

  fluidRow(
    column(2,
          h6("DYNAMIC LIST"),

          fluidRow(
            column(12,
            selectInput("get.id",label="ID NUMBER", setNames(as.list(dframe$gcode),dframe$date)),

            actionButton("submit1", "SUBMIT"),

            )
          ))
          ,

    column(10, 

           plotOutput("p.plot", height=800, width="auto"),
           br(),


           fluidRow(
             column(5,
              div(dataTableOutput("table1"), style = "font-size:85%")),
                    #dataTableOutput("table1")),
           column(5, offset=1,
              div(dataTableOutput("table2"), style = "font-size:85%"))
              #dataTableOutput("table2"))
           )

  )#end fluid row width of page(#1)
 )
))
```

The plot function is tied to the submit button through Observe.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If people are reading this question - I think the way to go is a RenderUI feature. I haven't had time to explore, but I believe this is the best solution - if anyone has experience with it, feel free to add a suggestion. I will continue to slowly move forward with it on my own as well.